# Android material design layout without expanded title

Tags: android

I am trying to build a layout that should look like this below.

[image]

So I am trying to use AppBarLayout for this purpose

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppBarExpanded"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/appartment2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The problem is that I can see the expanded title appearing in the bottom of the picture. How can I get rid of it and display title only when the layout is collapsed (scrolled up so that the picture is hidden)?

Comment: I believe the `exitUntilCollapsed` tells the picture to completely hide when you scroll up. Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: The picture is not an issue, the title itself is. I do not want to see a title when the toolbar is expanded.

Comment: The string, or the entire toolbar itself? I think in either case, you'll probably need a Java callback to say "onExpanded", or something